# Typographische Konvention zum bis-Strich in der Fraktur

Tags: blackletter, typography

Jemand sagte mir, dass der Halbgeviertstrich »–« in der Fraktur nicht verwandt wurde. Wie hat man dann in der Fraktur Bereiche ausgedrückt? Im Antiquasatz verwendet man den Halbgeviertstrich als »bis-Strich«:

> Das Café hat 8–16 Uhr geöffnet.

Wie schreibt man selbiges in der Fraktur? Ich habe gehört, man könne diesen durch eine Tilde oder einen Doppelbindestrich ersetzen:

> Das Café hat 8⸗16 Uhr geöffnet.
>   Das Café hat 8~16 Uhr geöffnet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laut [Matthias Kammerer](http://www.matthias-kammerer.de/SonsTypo5.htm#bisstrich) wird für den Bis-Strich in der Fraktur ein „emdash“ verwendet:

> Für die Angabe von Bereichen wird ebenfalls der »m«-breite Gedankenstrich verwendet, so beispielsweise bei Seiten- oder Versangaben (i.S.v. »bis«):

[image]

Comment: Verzeihung, ich habe nicht recht verstanden. Könnten Sie die Beispiele umschreiben?

Comment: @Gigili Meinen Sie die Beispiele in Fraktur? Oder das Zitat?

Comment: Die Beispiele .

Comment: @Gigili: "Lesen Sie die Seiten 35–68." "Die berühmten Anfangsworte im Johannes-Evangelium in Kapitel 1, Vers 1–5."

Comment: Die Beispiel dienen lediglich zur Veranschaulichung der Verwendung des „Bis-Strich“ in einer Fraktur-Schrift. Erster Satz: „Lesen Sie die Seiten 35–68.“ Zweiter Satz: „Die berühmten Anfangsworte im Johannes-Evangelium in Kapitel 1, Vers 1–5.“